# I am trying to create a custom firebase database class keep getting errors

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a custom firebase database class. I am trying to extract the data out of the database using observeSingleEvent function and assign it to a variable and return that variable. The problem is I am going the error " Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" but I know my code works because I use it outside that class. Heres where I declare my class variable and where I call it.

```
class MainMenuController: UIViewController {
    var db: DataBase!

    func readCheckings() {
        self.checkAmLbl.text = db.readMonth()!
    }
}
```

Here is my DataBase class:

```
class DataBase {

    private var ref: DatabaseReference {
        return Database.database().reference()
    }

    var uid: String? = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!


    func readMonth() -> String? {
        var check: String? = ""
        self.ref.child("Account Data").child(uid!).child("November 2017").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
            let checkings = value["Checkings"] as! Double
            check = String(checkings)
        })
        return check
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the `readMonth()` method design. You need to *wait* for Firebase to complete before returning your `check` value.

Try this instead:

```
func readMonth(completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
    self.ref.child("Account Data").child(uid!).child("November 2017").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { 
        (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
        let checkings = value["Checkings"] as! Double
        let check = String(checkings)
        completion(check)
    }
}
```

then call it like this:

```
func readCheckings() {
    db.readMonth { (check) in
        self.checkAmLbl.text = check!
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, you need also to create the object. Replace `var db: DataBase!` with `var db = DataBase()`.